# How to make TS infer presence of a property when an object is defined statically?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I have an interface that is extended by other types. For this question, I will simplify it as much as I can.

So, this interface defines an optional method `getColor`.
I'm defining an object that implements that interface, and statically defines the method `getColor`, which means the method will always be present.

But, if I try to call `ITEM_CONFIG.getColor`, ts complains with "Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.".

How can I make ts infer that in this case, that method is always present

```
interface NodeConfig<T extends object | AnyItemData> {
  getColor?: (data: T) => string;
}

export const ITEM_CONFIG: NodeConfig<ItemData> = {
  getColor: (data) => '#ff0000',
};
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use `Partial` outside when needed instead of optional `getColor`?

Answer (score 0):

You could add `as const` and check whether the constant is compatible with NodeConfig. Something like this:

```
type AnyItemData = { a: string; }

interface NodeConfig<T extends object | AnyItemData> {
  getColor?: (data: T) => string;
}

const validateConfig = (_config: NodeConfig<AnyItemData>) => {}; // no-op

const ITEM_CONFIG = {
  getColor: (data: AnyItemData) => '#ff0000',
} as const;

validateConfig(ITEM_CONFIG); // compiler will complain here if config is not compatible

console.log(ITEM_CONFIG.getColor({a: "my type"}));
```

You could also just write explicit types and use `Partial` as suggested by @Anatoly:

```
type AnyItemData = { a: string; }

type FullNodeConfig<T extends object | AnyItemData> = {
    getColor: (data: T) => string;
};

type NodeConfig<T extends object | AnyItemData> = Partial<FullNodeConfig<T>>;

const ITEM_CONFIG: FullNodeConfig<AnyItemData> = {
  getColor: (data: AnyItemData) => '#ff0000',
} as const;

console.log(ITEM_CONFIG.getColor({a: "my type"}));
```